# Is there a way to modify the gmail unread badge to show the number of new emails since last open?

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail

Currently, when `Unread message icon` is enabled, gmail will display the total number of unread emails in your inbox.

I personally cannot be bothered to clear out my inbox, so this number becomes completely useless to me.

[image]

Is there a way change this badge to display the number of new emails since the tab was last opened, or maybe even just unread emails from `Today`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it only checks your inbox folder for all unread messages. Your only options to use this specific icon feature involve managing your inbox

---

You could

- Brute force it: Select > All > Select all conversations in primary > Mark as read
- Set up a rule/script to archive old items or move them to another folder
- Or install an extension that supports the kind of filtering your looking for

Comment: I like the idea of auto-archiving at the end of the day.